# Cordova: ERROR: Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get Phone-gap to work, I followed this tutorial: http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu/. I am one Ubuntu 13.10. I have tried many different solutions found on stack-overflow and others, and non of them work.
The export I am using:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Running command: /hdd/Fred/Documents/phonegap/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ERROR: Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
Error: /hdd/Fred/Documents/phonegap/helloworld/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command  failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Please help.

Comment: I guess, Andrid home should be till sdk and not tool.

Answer (score 1):

@Rupesh is correct - set `ANDROID_HOME` to the sdk dir, not the tools dir.

So you don't have to do this each time you open a terminal, pop it into your `.bashrc` in your home dir:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/"
```

(As the error you get implies, if `ANDROID_HOME` is set, you shouldn't need to modify your `PATH`, but I guess it can't do any harm)

If that still doesn't work, check that the sdk path is actually correct.